# elegantly creating strings within sequence in R for ggplot2 axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to label a ggplot with years but maintain 3 monthly tick marks,  so require:

```
labels = c(0,"","","", 12,"","","", 24,"","","", 36...)
```

slightly neater is:

```
labels = c(0,rep("",3),12,rep("",3),24,rep("",3),36...)
```

It must be possible to programatically create this.

```
gsub("," , ",'','',''," ,"0,12,24,36" )
```

is close,  but the only actual working solution I've managed is

```
labels=c()
for (i in 0:3){ labels<-c(labels,i*12,rep("",3)) }
```

I'm sure there must be an elegant solution can anyone come up with one?

Comment: I think your solution looks quite elegant. You could also do `lapply`: `unlist(lapply(seq(0, 40, 12), c, rep("", 3)))`

Comment: `ggplot2:::interleave(letters[1:3], "", "", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a vector using `seq` and use the modulo operator (`%%`) to blank out entries I didn't want...

```
# Some data
df <- data.frame( x=seq(0,36) , y = rnorm(37) )

# Make quarterly labels  
lab <- seq(0,36,by=3)

# Blank everything that is not evenly divisible by 12 months
lab[ lab %% 12 > 0 ] <- ""

# Plot
ggplot( df , aes(x,y) ) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous( breaks = seq(0,36,by=3) , labels = lab )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will create the sequence for 10 years (40 entries)

```
lbls <- rep("", 40)   ## start empty vector
lbls[1+4*0:9] <- 12*0:9   ## selectively replace values with multiples of 12
```

I hope that helps.